# Set an html cell to a static width when creating a table for a mobile, blackberry app

Tags: html, css-tables, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to create a simple html/Javascript app for Blackberry 10. I'm having an issue with the following CSS code:

```
td
{
    width:100px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

It works correctly in Chrome on my laptop, however when I test it on my device I find the width shrinks to just cover the contents of the cell. The contents of the cell is definitely under 100px.

I have a feeling it might have something to do with how I am setting up the meta viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Did you use table for layout your content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rick, setting min width did the trick.

```
td
{
    min-width:100px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set the viewport like this:

`<script>
  var meta = document.createElement("meta");
      meta.setAttribute('name','viewport');
      meta.setAttribute('content','initial-scale='+ (1/window.devicePixelRatio) + ',user-scalable=no');
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
</script>`